# Can anyone please explain Automatic Global Registration of Base Components in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I studied the documentation for automatic global generation of base components  but it is confusing.  Can anyone please explain it in detail?

Comment: reference:[link] (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `require.context()` in order to resolve a directory where components live during webpack's build process. this exposes to you, within the browser, the list of files in that directory. From that, you can use some magic to automatically register them, here's an example:

```
const files = require.context('./components', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
```

So in the above, we've said that we want webpack to create a context for us of all files in the `'./components'` directory. From there, we can loop over all the keys of the files (which represent the file name) and register them with `Vue.component(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend watching this video:

https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/global-components

First you can understand why you may want to use global components, then why you would want to  automatically global register those components, and then what the registration  code (taken from the following link) actually does.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components